# Clarification about Cassandra tombstones and manual compaction

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, tombstone

I have few questions about Cassandra tombstones and manual compaction.

Let's say that I delete a row (partition key) in my Cassandra cluster at time X. Let's assume that `gc_grace_seconds` has its default value (ten days).

1. Is it true that if manually start a `nodetool compact` at a time lower than X+10 days the old data will be still on disk after the compaction ?
2. Instead, if I start `nodetool compact` at a time higher than X+10 days the old data is really removed from disk ?
3. Let's assume that the delete was issued at time X and later on I change the `gc_grace_seconds` to a lower value (let's say 1 day). If at time X+2 days I start `nodetool compact` the old data will be really removed from disk ? In other words the tombstone, when created, contains the deletion time and not the expiration time, right ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that if manually start a nodetool compact at a time lower than X+10 days the old data will be still on disk after the compaction ?

Yes tombstones are not removed if compaction is run before gc_grace_seconds.

> Instead, if I start nodetool compact at a time higher than X+10 days the old data is really removed from disk ?

Generally yes but depends on compaction strategy also. So you cannot be 100% sure of this.

> Let's assume that the delete was issued at time X and later on I change the gc_grace_seconds to a lower value (let's say 1 day). If at time X+2 days I start nodetool compact the old data will be really removed from disk ? In other words the tombstone, when created, contains the deletion time and not the expiration time, right ?

Yes you are correct on this. Tombstones contains deletion time. Expiry depends on gc_grace_seconds value of the table.

You should generally not run nodetool compact command (major compcations) and your compactions should be running automatically (minor compactions).

Comment: Are you 100% sure about the new gc_grace_seconds applied only to new data ? Looking at articles like the following it seems that the tombstone includes the timestamp at which the DELETE command was issued: https://medium.com/walmartglobaltech/tombstones-in-apache-cassandra-d0a068a72dcc